# How do i encrypt with my dictionary

Tags: python

Hi so i created this dictionary

```
cipher_dict = {'a':'d','b':'e','c':'f','d':'g','e':'h','f':'i','g':'j','h':'k','i':'l',
'j':'m','k':'n','l':'o','m':'p','n':'q','o':'r','p':'s','q':'t','r':'u','s':'v','t':'w',
'u':'x','v':'y','w':'z','x':'a','y':'b','z':'c','A':'D','B':'E','C':'F','D':'G','E':'H',
'F':'I','G':'J','H':'K','I':'L','J':'M','K':'N','L':'O','M':'P','N':'Q','O':'R','P':'S',
'Q':'T','R':'U','S':'V','T':'W','U':'X','V':'Y','W':'Z','X':'A','Y':'B','Z':'C'}
```

My question is, can I use this for encryption and decryption ? If yes, how can I make the keys and values become strings?

For example if I want to encrypt `"ROADWAY"` how could I do it with my dictionary?

I am really new to programming and I will be very appreciative of any help I can get to understand this.

Comment: Please read this before post question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will encrypt `message` with your dictionary:

```
message = 'ROAD#WAY'
encrypted = ''

for x in message:
    if cipher_dict.get(x):
        encrypted += cipher_dict[x]

print(encrypted)
```

If a character in `message` is not in your dictionary, it will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it like this:

```
word_to_encrypt='this is a test'

cipher_dict = {' ':'#','a':'d','b':'e','c':'f','d':'g','e':'h','f':'i','g':'j','h':'k','i':'l', 'j':'m','k':'n','l':'o','m':'p','n':'q','o':'r','p':'s','q':'t','r':'u','s':'v','t':'w', 'u':'x','v':'y','w':'z','x':'a','y':'b','z':'c','A':'D','B':'E','C':'F','D':'G','E':'H', 'F':'I','G':'J','H':'K','I':'L','J':'M','K':'N','L':'O','M':'P','N':'Q','O':'R','P':'S', 'Q':'T','R':'U','S':'V','T':'W','U':'X','V':'Y','W':'Z','X':'A','Y':'B','Z':'C'} 

decrypt_dict=dict((v,k) for k,v in cipher_dict.items())

encrypted_word=''.join(cipher_dict[letter] for letter in word_to_encrypt)
decrypted_word=''.join(decrypt_dict[letter] for letter in encrypted_word)

print(word_to_encrypt)
print(encrypted_word)
print(decrypted_word)
```

The only problem with this method is that if th word you want to encrypt has characters that are missing in the dictionary it will bug.

By the way, you will probably get negative votes on your question because you didn't make any effort to code. StackOverflow is not a site to request code and make people do your work!

Happy hacking

Comment: Thank you. i have actually been on it for some days now . Like i said i am new to programming . its not like i didn"t make an effort towards the code

Answer (score 0):

String='this is what I need'

Diction = {' ':'#','a':'d','b':'e','c':'f','d':'g','e':'h','f':'i','g':'j','h':'k','i':'l', 'j':'m','k':'n','l':'o','m':'p','n':'q','o':'r','p':'s','q':'t','r':'u','s':'v','t':'w', 'u':'x','v':'y','w':'z','x':'a','y':'b','z':'c','A':'D','B':'E','C':'F','D':'G','E':'H', 'F':'I','G':'J','H':'K','I':'L','J':'M','K':'N','L':'O','M':'P','N':'Q','O':'R','P':'S', 'Q':'T','R':'U','S':'V','T':'W','U':'X','V':'Y','W':'Z','X':'A','Y':'B','Z':'C'}

encrypted_string = ""

for chr in String:

```
  if Diction.get(chr):
    encrypted_string = encrypted_string + Diction[chr]
```

print encrypted_string

This is exact what you need

Comment: Actually I am new to stackoverflow